# Need to automount dvd or cdrom at fixed mount point in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: compact-disc, ubuntu-11.04, automount, hal

Ubuntu 11.04, by default, automounts a cdrom or dvd at /media/<vol_name>.  I need to make the automounting system use a fixed name instead of the volume name for all CDs or DVDs inserted into this particular drive, e.g. "/media/op-drive0".  A bit of searching turns up pretty much the same solution I used, successfully, on an older, gentoo box, which is to create an fdi file for hal, along the lines of the instructions at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=91450.  This doesn't seem to work on this box.  Other sources say to use the gnome-mount utility to set the mounting properties.  Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't know about the gnome-mount program.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot you not install gnome-mount in 11.04?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Installation

Answer (score 2):

I can't guarantee it will work under GNOME because I use KDE, but if I add a line for the DVD drive in `/etc/fstab` like you used to need in older Linux distributions:

```
/dev/dvd /media/dvd auto user,noauto,exec,utf8 0
```

and ensure that the mount point `/media/dvd` exists, then any time I access a DVD using the Dolphin file browser, the automount happens at the fixed mount point, ignoring the volume label.

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sr1 on /media/dvd type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,utf8,user=orbweaver)
```

It appears that the automounting system uses the contents of `/etc/fstab` to override its default behaviour, but again this *could* be KDE-specific.

Comment: Thanks.  I do recall trying this in Gentoo some time ago, and it didn't work.  I believe automounting went away and I had to explicitly mount the medium when I inserted a CD or DVD.  There are a number of commented-out lines in /etc/fstab on that box as a record of this experiment.  But it looks as if things have come a long way :)  I think your solution will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue off-and-on for a few months.  The DVD will work fine and load different DVD-s quite happily most of the time.  Then every now and then, like last night, DVD-s stop loading.  It isn't very consistient.

The first time this happened one DVD didn't auto-mount, and another did, while a third that I'd watched earlier would not auto-mount.

Today I restarted `udev` ... and inserted a DVD that was not auto-mounting.  It auto-mounted just like a bought-one. Great!

```
$ service  udev  restart
$ service  udev  status
$ eject -t  #  Close DVD-ROM drive
```

That's a nice clean way about it I think.